# Find where an Indexformula is pointing through VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a VBA script that would look through a range and convert index, Vlookup, HLookup, Offset etc formulas and re-write them into a static reference.

Example

A1: A

A2: b

A3: c

=index(A1:A3, 2, 1) gives "b"

I would like to, through VBA change this formula to:

=A2

Can this be done? How?

Thank you * 1000!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This small macro gets the formula and first discards both the "=INDEX(" and the ")" parts.

It then splits apart the three arguments.  The first argument is treated as the range address.  The second and third arguments are used to get the offsets:

```
Sub MakeReplacement()
    Dim rrow As Long, ccol As Long
    Dim dest As Range
    s = ActiveCell.Formula
    s2 = Mid(s, 8)
    ary = Split(Left(s2, Len(s2) - 1), ",")
    rrow = Evaluate(ary(1)) - 1
    ccol = Evaluate(ary(2)) - 1
    Set dest = Range(ary(0))(1).Offset(rrow, ccol)
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & dest.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```